# node can't connect to Mongo -- Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I try to start my express server with `node index.js` I get the following error message:

```
*path/to/project*/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND undefined undefined:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)
```

There are many questions on Stack Overflow with similar error messages but they are mostly due to either not running mongod or typos.

I am running mongod, I can connect to mongo via the terminal. I changed some code and hit some errors, but then started fresh from working code. The current code worked to connect to MongoDB before (and production version works with the same code).

I can also run an express server and connect to MongoDB on the same machine with different node projects with similar setups.

Comment: seems as if the params that you are passing to your mongo's connection string are not reaching there. Try printing them using `console.log()` right before using them for connection.

Comment: @vikramTiwari Somehow what I was able to do to fix it was change:

`if (process.env.ENV == 'staging' ){
 db = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else if (process.env.ENV == 'production' ){
 db = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
 db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pcAPI');
}`

to

`if (process.env.ENV == 'staging' || 'production' ){
 db = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
 db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pcAPI');
}`

No idea why this was throwing it off, even weirder because it worked before.

Comment: It should have been using the third one anyway, and is now when it's working . . .

Comment: Dude! Your current condition (`if (process.env.ENV == 'staging' || 'production') {`) is wrong. It will always be true and will use `process.env.MONGODB_URI`.

Comment: You are connected to database that is in your `process.env.MONGODB_URI`. The connection string that you are using is somehow incorrect. `mongodb://localhost/pcAPI`.
Run this program to check for yourself. 
`var process = {
 env: {
  ENV: ''
 }
};

if (process.env.ENV == 'staging') {
 console.log('1');
} else if (process.env.ENV == 'production') {
 console.log('2');
} else {
 console.log('3');
}

if (process.env.ENV == 'staging' || 'production') {
 console.log('11');
} else {
 console.log('12');
}`

Comment: @VikramTiwari Why would it always be true if neither one individually is true?

The first line of your code is giving the same error, seems like a problem with environment variables?:

`var process = { env: { ENV: '' } };
undefined
TypeError: process.nextTick is not a function`

Comment: Run that code to understand that you if condition is wrong. Not in production. Your if condition is wrong cause of this `(process.env.ENV == 'staging' || 'production')` is not equal to `(process.env.ENV == 'staging' || process.env.ENV == 'production')`

Comment: Got it, very confused as to how this was working before with the same code, but I'll never be able to reproduce the past.  Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Check what is `process.env.MONGODB_URI` in your terminal. That should be helpful.

Comment: It's not set, which is the weird part, and why I thought I would be ok with the conditional above.

But you're right `'staging' || 'production'` is still coming up as true, while each individually come up as false.